# get data from subcollection Flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Help me get docs from subcollection please. Non of the answers seem to help me.

My code:

```
StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("ADS")
                      .doc(my doc id)
                      .collection(subcollection name)
                      .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){

                     final name = snapshot.doc!["The date I want to get"] .....//here I want to get only the specific data but it's giving me error. How do I go about it?
}
)
```

Comment: "but it's giving me error" What error? Please edit your question to show the exact message, and its stack trace. --- I also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as the closer you stay to the recipe outlined there, the better the chance that someone here can help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `doc` api in snapshot parameter, I don't know what exactly data you trying to get, but should look more like this:

```
StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("ADS")
                      .doc(my doc id)
                      .collection(subcollection name)
                      .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
                      // Get first document in collection.
                      final firstDoc = snapshot.docs[0];
})
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. I maybe my code is wrong. If it is can u help me correct it. I want to get access to each data in a collectionGroup